# Converting String to Interger

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to change the color of text by applying a condition. I'm getting the text from Json. Code is working fine **without** that "check for the color change" part present at the end of the code. Otherwise, It isn't returning anything. app crashes. What's the problem??

Here is the code :

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(jsonResposnce);
            JSONArray jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("items");


            for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jo = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                String itemName = jo.getString("itemName");
                String Power = jo.getString("Power");
                String RH = jo.getString("RH");
                String DAILYDATE = jo.getString("DAILYDATE");
                String TPH = jo.getString("TPH");
                String Production = jo.getString("Production");



                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<>();
                item.put("itemName", itemName);
                item.put("Power", Power);
                item.put("RH", RH);
                item.put("TPH", TPH);
                item.put("DAILYDATE", DAILYDATE);
                item.put("Production", Production);

                list.add(item);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>>(this, R.layout.listdaily_row,
                R.id.yx_item_name, list) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View rowView = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                final HashMap<String, String> item = getItem(position);

                TextView itemName = rowView.findViewById(R.id.yx_item_name);
                itemName.setText(item.get("itemName"));
                TextView Power = rowView.findViewById(R.id.yx_power);
                Power.setText(item.get("Power"));
                TextView RH = rowView.findViewById(R.id.yx_rh);
                TextView TPH = rowView.findViewById(R.id.yx_tph);
                TPH.setText(item.get("TPH"));
                TextView DAILYDATE = rowView.findViewById(R.id.yx_date);
                DAILYDATE.setText(item.get("DAILYDATE"));
                TextView Production = rowView.findViewById(R.id.yx_prod);
                Production.setText(item.get("Production"));


                // check for the color change

                String check = item.get("RH");
                if (check != null && Integer.parseInt(check) >= 10) {
                    RH.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    RH.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                RH.setText(item.get("RH"));


                return rowView;
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: paste the exception message too... please

Comment: It shows loading dialog for few seconds and then screen goes blank. Later, shows app stopped working

Comment: No error in building the app. Problem after running the activity

Comment: Please have a look at [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this) to get the crash log that people are asking for.

Comment: Try printing the value of `check`, most probably it's not a numeric string. It's better to add a vlidation of this string before using it in the if statement.

Comment: In locat it shows the error :  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" Problem lies in the If condition line. I don't know why?? what's wrong here

Comment: If you were given a string "" which number would you make of it? `Integer.parseInt()` can't parse an empty string.

Comment: Thanks @Markus. There was some null values and decimal values which was causing the error. Somehow I can't remove null and decimal values from my item list(accessing it from gsheet). Is there any other method other than 'Integer.parseInt' to deal with it while having null and decimal values.?? I can use float for decimal values. But what should be used for handling null ??

Comment: What about a simple `if (check != null && !check.isEmpty() && Integer.parseInt(check) >= 10) {...}`?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the null string. So I modified the check part to handle null value issue, as shown below and now it's working.

// check price

```
            String checkPrice = item.get("RH");

            int check = 0;
            try
            {
                if(checkPrice != null)
                    check = Integer.parseInt(checkPrice);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                check = 0;
            }


                if (check>= 10) {
                    RH.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    RH.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
                RH.setText(item.get("RH"));

            return rowView;
        }
    });
```